# Tabular has empty row after hline

Tags: tables

I made 100 of tabulars like this and never had this problem. I want to end the tabular with an `\hline`, but after that there is a new line with 2 lines. How do I get rid of it?

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
- & private & onzichtbaar voor de buitenwereld\\
+ & public & zichtbaar voor de buitenwereld \\
\# & protected & zichtbaar voor subklassen\\
$\sim$ & geen naam & zichtbaar voor alles in dezelfde package\\
\hline
\centering
\end{tabular}
\caption{Visibiliteit van toestand en gedrag}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the *second* `\centering` (just before `\end{tabular}`) it is doing nothing other than causing a blank row.

Comment: I knew it was going to be a stupid mistake... I didn't know you don't have to close the centering tag.

Comment: @Aaron: As a rule of thumb, you only have to close something of the form `\begin{...}`.

Comment: as Mohan said, also if you had done `\begin{center}` instead of the first `\centering` you would have needed the closing `\end{center}` to come _after_ `\end{tabular}` so environment nesting works out correctly.